# reorder cells dynamically through code(without dragging cell) with the animation

Tags: iphone

I have sorted data coming from server and I am displaying it on tableview, however, there is a another functionality on cell, that If I do that functionality, cells should be rearranged accordingly.

I want to have animation like reordering cell using reordercontrol of table view cell.

Does anyone know, how to animate like reordering cells?

Answer (score 1):

[Check this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) at Matt Gallagher's blog [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/).
It has a great project that shows how to animate rows and a lot of cool stuff about customizing UITableviews.